# Need to show Term Of Use when customer or user logged in first time in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm New in Magento2, I need to show Term Of Use when user logged in first time in Magento2. How to do it. kindly give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with free extension like this https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-redirect-customer